How to get AppDataDirecoty path with consol command?
I'm saving some data in my 'FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory' path. From time to time I need to get into that catalog and delete some files that I created there and there is a problem I am encountering. Is there a way to get the path to that directory from Visual Studio's console so I don't have to debug through the line string DataPath = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory; every time?
